# write a code in c to find how many Fridays fell on the fifth of the month from 1 Jan 1801 to 31 Dec 2000, given 24 March 2002 was a Wednesday?

Tags: c, algorithm, date, logic

I was given this question to solve. My code outputs 316 but some suggest 345 is a correct answer. I don't know if my code works properly or not since I use the Sakamoto algorithm to calculate the weekday of a given day, month, and year. Since the actual date for 24 March, 2002 is Sunday instead of Wednesday (0 is Sunday ... 6 is Saturday). I add 3 (as a constant variable) in an algorithm. This is where I am a bit hesitant whether I make the right choice or not. However, I think that a shift does not affect anything so is this supposed to work?? Alternatively, I could set the weekday to Tuesday instead of Friday without any constant.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int howManyDays() {
    int sakamoto();
    
    int starting_weekday = 3;
    int result = sakamoto(24,3,2002,0);
    int constant = starting_weekday - result;

    int calculated_year = 1801;
    int calculated_month = 1;
    int count = 0;

    do {
        int calculated_weekday = sakamoto(5, calculated_month, calculated_year, constant);
        //int calculated_weekday = (calculated_day+constant+day_in_months[calculated_month-1]) % 7;

        if (calculated_weekday == 5) {
            count += 1;
        }

        calculated_month += 1;

        if (calculated_month == 12) {
            calculated_month = 1;
            calculated_year += 1;
        } 

    } while(!(calculated_month == 1 && calculated_year == 2001));
    return count;
}

int sakamoto(int d, int m, int y, int c) {
    int offset[] = {0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4}; // 0->Sunday ... 2->Tuesday ... 6->Saturday
    y -= m < 3;

    return (y + y / 4 - y / 100 + y / 400 + offset[m - 1] + d + c) % 7;

}


int main() {
    int a = howManyDays();
    printf("result: %d", a);
}
```

Could anyone confirm whether what I think is correct or completely false??
Thanks in Advance, Hope you have a wonderful time :)

Comment: The range has 2400 months (200 years) and there are seven possible days on which the fifth could fall. So you'd expect that about 2400/7 months would satisfy the condition. Since seven doesn't divide 2400, it's not going to be exact and anyway the vagueries of the Gregorian cycle impose some variations, but you'd expect it to not deviate much. 2401/7 = 343, so 345 seems plausible while 316 doesn't. (Indeed, afaics 345 is the correct answer.)

Comment: @rici Thanks for an advice, I agreed with u. However, I thought that using sakamoto algorithm must produce the same result 345. Why isn't that the case??

Comment: I guess you have a bug in your implementation. Did you test it on some known dates?

Comment: @rici yes, I have tested it. It produces correct dates. That's why I am confused why it does not produce the correct answer?

Comment: @rici Perhaps, I have implemented a shift in weekday wrong since 24 March 2002 is actually Sunday instead of Wednesday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your months range from `1` to `11`. Since you're not counting Fridays in December, your results are off by about 1/12th and indeed 345*11/12 = 316.25.